# Getting G_NORMAL_MAP is not defined error using gmap

Tags: jquery, jquery-gmap3

I am trying to use gmap which uses jquery to easily integrate Google maps on a website. The problem is every time I try to use it, no matter what settings I use I never see the map and I always get this error in firebug:

G_NORMAL_MAP is not defined

The website itself seems to still use v2 of the google map api, which requires a key when including it like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&amp;v=2&amp;key=API_KEY"></script>
```

But of course v2 has been deprecated, I cant even register to get a api key anymore. Im thinking this is part of the problem? If so does anyone know if gmap can still work with the latest version of the google map api? If so how do I include the proper api script for this error to go away? I tried this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
```

But I still get the same error. I place the script include in the header of the my page, Im assuming that is the correct location? I did find another post on stack overflow with a similar issue but this was with v2 and the api key. I believe this is a different issue. All Im trying to do is find a jquery solution that works with the latest google map api that allows me to feed it multiple lat/lon location to display the points on the map. Any suggestions/help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok didnt do enough research, they have an update with the latest version of google maps:

http://labs.mario.ec/jquery-gmap/#docs